# Django authentication override not working

Tags: python, django, authentication

I created a file "authentication.py" at the same level as the "settings.py" file in my django project. The content of this file is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SettingsBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        user_name = 'user_name'
        user_password = 'user_pass'
        login_valid = (user_name == username)
        pwd_valid = (password == user_password)
        if login_valid and pwd_valid:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User(username=username)
                user.is_staff = True
                user.is_superuser = True
                user.save()
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then I added the following line in the "settings.py" file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('myProject.authentication.SettingsBackend',)
```

However, the login doesn't work. It was working before these 2 modification when the user's credentials where stored in the database. I don't know how I can debug this. Any idea ?

Here are some pieces of my settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'default',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates/"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}




# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout'
ADMIN_ENABLED = False
```

**EDIT**: I deleted the "db.sqlite3" file at the root of my folder, then ran the django shell and did:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session.objects.all().delete()
```

Then I get this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(username='user_name')
>> DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: You can try to debug it by setting a breakpoint or logging statements in `SettingsBackend.authenticate()`

Comment: Any print() or logging doesn't shows up.. I don't really know how django actually use this file.

Comment: Try running `authenticate(None, username='user_name', password='user_pass')` from the django shell (`manage.py shell`)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

Comment: Right, didn't know about the django shell... it does return a user object (<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>) if credentials are good, and None if not.

Comment: Might it be possible that django isn't calling the my own authenticate in the application ? As if the default 'login' view didn't use the defined default  AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS

Comment: What is the error message you get when you fail to log in?

Comment: I don't get any error. Just the classic "please provide an existing account" or something like that.

Comment: You don't know what response you get?

Comment: I get "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

Comment: Go to the shell, get the user `user = User.objects.get(username='user_name')`. Check that the user is active `user.active == True` and is staff `user.is_staff == True`.

Comment: I get a "DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist."

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user =  list(User.objects.all())
print(user)

and check if username exists.

Comment: Obviously the user was not created. The problem was indeed that version 1.10 of django doesn't take request as parameter in the authentication function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised the code didn't work and investigated it.

Please note there is a difference between django versions:

The request param for a custom backend seems to be added in 1.11.
If you are running a version <1.11 remove the request param.

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
```

[Django 1.10 writing-an-authentication-backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

[Django 1.11 writing-an-authentication-backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

I debugged it by investigating [def authenticate(...)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py) in django source, it loops through all backends.

Comment: Amazing work man. I'm using 1.10 indeed ! Do you thing Django developpers should have put more security for this kind of upgrade ? Or I've just been neglecting...

Comment: I just spotted myself that it was actually documented (that the request param was added in 1.11). The documentation is usually quite good and it is pretty hard to manage compatibility when creating frameworks. I guess we have to read more carefully next time :-).

Answer (score 1):

You might try to run:

```
Session.objects.all().delete().
```

Before testing new auth backend. [From the Django docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/)

> Once a user has authenticated, Django stores which backend was used to
>   authenticate the user in the user’s session, and re-uses the same
>   backend for the duration of that session whenever access to the
>   currently authenticated user is needed. This effectively means that
>   authentication sources are cached on a per-session basis, so if you
>   change AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, you’ll need to clear out session data
>   if you need to force users to re-authenticate using different methods.
>   A simple way to do that is simply to execute
>   Session.objects.all().delete().

Comment: Thx for pointing that out. I updated my post to explain what I did so far. It doesn't help so far.